# How do you test, mock context in React tests?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have code like that:

```
render () {
  ...

  const {
    exampleMethod,
  } = this.props;

  const { getPath } = this.context;
  const exampletData = exampleMethod(getPath());

  ...
}
```

How can i mock, test context in this example? And how do you test context in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `enzyme` you can set the context when shallow rendering or full dom rendering by passing an option. ([docs here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper)):

eg:

```
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

// ......

const testContext = { getPath: () => 'foo' };
const shallowWrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />, { context: testContext });

// or 

const fullWrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />, { context: testContext });
```

If you want to test the context on a node you can use the [.context()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/context.html) method from `enzyme`